# jQuery submit not working with scriptManager

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a webform with a `<input type="button" OnClick="DoSubmit()">` and this executes the function:

```
function DoSubmit()
{
    if (ComprobarFecha())
    {           
        $("#paraCrear").val(1);
        $("#frmMain").submit();
    }
}
```

On jQuery.

Till here was working, but after inserting a scriptmanager, the button is not working anymore. I debug it with chrome and I see that the `$("#frmMain").submit();` is not getting an error, but is not doing anything.

The code of the form is this:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="frmMain" name="frmMain" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">  
  <Services>  
      <asp:ServiceReference Path="/WS.asmx" />  
  </Services>  
  </asp:ScriptManager>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Why do you use jQuery to post your form? Let the asp.net framework handle that.

Comment: with that, I can control some validations, I don't know how to do it with asp.net

Comment: Use [Validation Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is that asp.net changes de name of the form when compiles it. So i made `document.forms[0].submit();` instead of the jQuery submit.

This is going to the first position of the array, and not searching it from name.

Answer (score 0):

In a default WebFroms project your code works with and without the ScriptManager and there is no logic it shouldn't.

If I have to guess, your problem might be coming from some additional script you haven't submitted in your question. Double check if you're not catching the submit event somewhere else and prevent its default behavior.

Comment: I'm only submitting there.

Comment: I've created a blank project with the samples you've provided (with small modifications for the missing stuff) and there were no issues. Double check IDs, JSs, etc.